Any smooth compact 2-dimensional submanifold $S\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ is orientable
A manifold $M$ is orientable if the bundle of antisymmetric $n$-linear forms $\Lambda^n(M)$ is trivial. Equivalently, $\Lambda^n(M)$ admits a nowhere vanishing section.
I suppose we must assume that $S$ has no boundary since otherwise the Möbius strip would be a counter example.
Ideas: I couldn't directly construct a nowhere vanishing section of $\Lambda^2(S)$. So I looked in Lee, Intro to Smooth Manifolds and found that it suffices to find a smooth unit normal vector field along $S$ (prop. 15.32). But how? Specially considering the case of the Möbius strip, for which such a vector field should not exist.

You need something like the Jordan-Brouwer Separation Theorem (see, for example, Guillemin-Pollack pp. 87-89) to deduce that a compact hypersurface (without boundary) bounds a region, and then the boundary orientation gives you an orientation on the hypersurface.

Thank you very much!
